# Open PL/SQL Library .pll content in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, oracleforms

Currently working with a project in Oracle Forms that uses a library that has packages and functions, and i want to see the content of those functions:

[image: Library used]

i have tried to double click on the sub-program and i tried to open it with PL/SQL editor but nothing. How can i see the content of the library to understand the uses of the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PLL file.
So you need to open the corresponding PLL file in you oracle forms developer

Normally it has the same name, so in your case it should be calendar.pll

Comment: My bad, i was trying to open the library in the wrong place